# Attack of the double-encoded &hellip;, part n

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, encoding

The `&hellip;` used when truncating the question body in the `title` attribute of links on the  front page is being double-encoded, as seen below:

[image: double-encoded hellip in titles]

Additionally, the space before the `&hellip;` should likely not be there. There's also an extra space after it as well, but I'm not sure if that's noticeable without looking at the source.

Comment: as reported on [Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/q/3305/4377)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This derives from the subtle difference between HTML Encoding, and Attribute Encoding.

We don't actually reach in to revision history to get the raw plain text of the Markdown for performance reasons, so we always start with the HTML version of the post... which *kind of works* for attributes, but HTML Encoding != Attribute Encoding.

Adding a new method to synthesize explicit plain text summaries here by (hack) using [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) rather than the previous "HTML with the tags removed" method, which isn't *really* correct.